# Changing Excel cell format in C#

Tags: c#, excel

How can I change the format of a cell in Excel using the Microsoft Excel 12.0 Library in C#? More specifically, I want to change a given cell to text format.

I have read [.net c# changing excel cell format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346927/net-c-changing-excel-cell-format), but the cell still says general (although it does display as text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the format you're actually trying to implement. There's not a silver bullet for changing to any format you want. If it's formatting numbers that you need, you could use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603013/number-formatting-in-excel-vb-net). I ran into a lot of suggestions to [create a macro](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2008/06/03/i-just-want-to-format-a-cell-in-my-excel-worksheet-norm-estabrook.aspx), you can do some pretty specific tasks that you define yourself.

Answer (score 1):

No need to do that just change the NumberFormat.

```
// Set all cells from A1 to B2 to be text
ws.get_Range("A1", "B2")).NumberFormat = "@";
```

different formats can be looked up here

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/number-format-codes-HP005198679.aspx